# Receiver or Service? Or maybe both..?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on New application in my company and it uses class NotificationMessagingService which extends FirebaseMessagingService().

It looks like this: (not whole code of class, just important parts)

```
class NotificationMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        DoSomeWork()
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

         DoSomeWork()
        }
        )
    }
}
```

But one thing confuses me. E**ven though this class is registered in manifest as service, it has a lot of elements of receiver to me**
Just look at documentation here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

It extends service and is service, but still it listens for messages from firebase (isn't this a receiver property to do listening part)
For me this looks like some kind of hybrid between receiver and service.
Can someone please explain this to me a little bit better?

Comment: Take a look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: bro you put same link i put at the problem description that confuses me :D

Comment: Okey according to my understanding , it is a service class related to firebase , it could be used for example in firebase FCM , device to device messaging like in chat apps , you basically post your values to fcm server and receive them  back in that function onMessageReceived() and handle your logic

Comment: Link 1 : https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuJb_BRDJARIsAKkycUm85_tbeDAG1ZhkrqncJSVUzAuQMHssQp2tLxzMnkQH_5fgRxNueSMaAvA5EALw_wcB

Comment: Link 2 : https://medium.com/mindorks/send-device-to-device-push-notification-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-without-using-external-769476c79ffd

Comment: Hope these links help you understand little bit more about it